# When is the wp-mail.php in the WP root requested?

Tags: core

I see there is this *wp-mail.php* file which seems to be a feature to open a mailbox via pop3 and grab a post to publish it.

But I wonder, when is this file being executed? It seems to not be used anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I wonder, when is this file being executed? It seems to not be used anymore.

The old Codex info here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email

mentions this being **deprecated** and recommends using plugins instead.

It seems to be the user's own responsibility to run `wp-mail.php` to fetch posts from the mailbox, either via hook, calling the file manually via browser or via a cron job. See the Codex link above for code examples.

This seems like a very slow deprecation as it still ships with WordPress core:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d61b86229736b550457ef7d61563e17c50de9561/wp-mail.php

The ticket to remove it is here:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22942

and the old dev blogs here:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/post-by-email/

Comment: Wow, well... that's a detailed and clear answer. Thank you!